# Filtering multiple columns via a list using %in% and filter in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

Ok so here's my imaginary `data.frame` called `data`

```
A1 A2 A3  A4  A5  A6     
1  2  45  35  33  38  
5  1  23  33  58  47
18 26 78  15  5   6
```

What I want do is select all rows that have a 1 or 33 in any of the columns

so my initial thought was to write the following code

```
a <- paste0("A",1:6)
num <- c("1","33")

data <- data %>%
  filter(a %in% num)
```

intuitively I though this would work but I keep getting the error Result must have length **_ not _**.

Any way I could get around this or use a different solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this with `filter_all`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c(1, 33)))
#  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6
#1  1  2 45 35 33 38
#2  5  1 23 33 58 47
```

If we need to do this on a subset of columns use `filter_at` and specify the column index or nameswithin `vars`

```
data %>%
   filter_at(vars(matches("A\\d+")), any_vars(. %in% c(1, 33)))
```

The `vars` can also take objects

```
a <- paste0("A", 1:6)
vals <- c(1, 33)
data %>% 
    filter_at(vars(a), any_vars(. %in%  vals))
```

Answer (score 2):

Back to base R:

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% c(1, 33))), ]
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6
1  1  2 45 35 33 38
2  5  1 23 33 58 47
```

Comment: Another `base R` option is `data[Reduce('|', lapply(data, '%in%', c(1, 33))), ]`

Answer (score 2):

How about this simple base R:

```
data[rowSums(data==33 | data==1)>=1,]

#  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6
#1  1  2 45 35 33 38
#2  5  1 23 33 58 47
```

In case you want to extend your filter

```
filter <- c(1,33)
data[rowSums(matrix(as.matrix(data) %in% filter, nrow(data), ncol(data)))>=1,]
```